# Showing sums for stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, stacked-chart

I have the following data frame:

```
#>    region product delivery price
#> 1   Japan  laptop      yes   500
#> 2   Japan  laptop       no   400
#> 3   Japan printer      n/a   200
#> 4 America  laptop       no   600
#> 5 America  laptop      yes   620
#> 6 America  laptop      yes   300
#> 7 America printer      n/a   300
#> 8   China  laptop      yes   400
```

reproduced here:

```
structure(list(region = c("Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "China"), product = c("laptop", 
"laptop", "printer", "laptop", "laptop", "laptop", "printer", 
"laptop"), delivery = c("yes", "no", "n/a", "no", "yes", "yes", 
"n/a", "yes"), price = c(500, 400, 200, 600, 620, 300, 300, 400
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

and the following code generates a bar chart comparing the price of laptops vs printers per region. Laptops have an option for delivery, so the laptop column is stacked with a "no" region and "yes" region.

```
ggplot(df, aes(product, y = price, fill = delivery)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  facet_grid(.~region, switch = "x")
```

[image]

On their respective columns, I need to show the sum price for laptops and printers by region, and for laptops, I also want to see the dum price for laptops with and without delivery. I have tried:

```
geom_text(aes(label = price), size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack")
```

However, this just shows all the individual prices on each column.

Comment: Could you attach the resulting plot from your code?

Comment: Done, slightly updated the dataset too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sum per stacked bar**

If you want to add the sum per column, I suggest you to calculate it beforehand and then prompt it.

```
# This calculates the totals per category
tots = df %>%
  group_by(region, product) %>%
  summarise(total=sum(price)) 

# This plots the results
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(product, y = price, fill = delivery)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  facet_grid(.~region, switch = "x") +
  geom_text(aes(product, total, fill= NULL, label = total), data=tots, size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack")
```

The `geom_text` use the `tots` dataframe which contains the totals to be prompted.

The result is the following:

[image]

**Adding subtotal per delivery**

No big difference, you just have to add a subtotal df and prompt both:

```r
tots = df %>%
  group_by(region, product) %>%
  summarise(total=sum(price)) 
stots = df %>%
  group_by(region, product, delivery) %>%
  summarise(stotal=sum(price)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(delivery))
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(product, y = price, fill = delivery)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  facet_grid(.~region, switch = "x") +
  geom_text(aes(product, stotal, fill= NULL, label = stotal), data=stots, size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(product, total, fill= NULL, label = total, fontface=2), data=tots, size = 4, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.5, position = "stack")
```

I did it (and change the fontface to be 2 so the total is bold)

[image]

**Adding the cumulative sum per delivery inside**

Pretty much the same trick, but aggregating the `tots` data before.
I did it by doing `arrange` and `mutate` on top of `summarise`, and precising delivery in the `group_by`.

```
tots2 = df %>%
  group_by(region, product, delivery) %>%
  summarise(total=sum(price)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(delivery)) %>% 
  mutate(cumtot=cumsum(total))
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(product, y = price, fill = delivery)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  facet_grid(.~region, switch = "x") +
  geom_text(aes(product, total, fill= NULL, label = cumtot), data=tots2, size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack")
```

Output:

[image]

**Cumulative sum**

I calculated the cumulated price before plotting it like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(region, product) %>%
  arrange(desc(delivery)) %>% 
  mutate(cum_price = cumsum(price)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(product, y = price, fill = delivery)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  facet_grid(.~region, switch = "x") +
  geom_text(aes(label = cum_price), size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack")
```

The `arrange`is added to ensure your sum is cumulated in the same order as your plot.

Result is the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is, I only want to see a single sum per region. So for example in the first column, I only want to see 920 in the blue section, 600 in the green section and then 1520 total above the bar.

Comment: My apologies for introducing ambiguity with the word "cumulative", I have rephrased with "sum"

Comment: No worries, I edited my answer to prompt both solutions

Comment: Is it possible to still get the sums for the individual stacks? i.e. (laptop) 920 for yes (without the constituent 620), 600 for no and 1520 in total?

Comment: Sure, I added it

Comment: Hey man, sorry to be a nuisance, but the values are still not correct. The first column needs to have the exact labels `920`, `600` and then the total of `1520`. Not  `920` and then the total of `1520`. Thanks! The idea is that I want to see the individual sums as well as the overall sum

Comment: Oh I see, then it's just combining the solutions 1 & 2, I edit my answer then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219266/discussion-between-arault-and-harry-stuart).